# Is there a way to get a function to return a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, counting

I am trying to write a function that will return a data frame. Basically the goal is to have three columns: one that lists a certain identifier, one that reports how often that identifier appears in one column of dataset A, and one that reports how often that identifier appears in one column of dataset B. I wrote this function and cannot figure out why it is printing rather than storing as a data frame. This is particularly mystifying because when I run the "if" loop outside of the function it creates the desired data frame. Any help would be appreciated.

A sample of the data would be:

```
UOF$identifier     Citations$identifier
1545               1712
1588               646
1640               1545
1545               1645
1545               646
1588               1545
                   1640
                   1640
```

And I would want this function to return:

```
value    instances in dataset 1    instances in dataset 2
1545     3                         2
1588     2                         0
1640     1                         2
```

```
  join_analysis<-function(column_name_fromdataset1, column_name_fromdataset2){
  Dataset1<-as.numeric(column_name_fromdataset1)
  Dataset2<-as.numeric(column_name_fromdataset2)
  unique_values1<-unique(Dataset1)  
  count<-data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=length(Dataset2),ncol=3))
  for (i in 1:length(unique_values1)){
    ID<-unique_values1[i]
    count[,3][i]<-sum(Dataset2==ID, na.rm = TRUE)
    count[,2][i]<-sum(Dataset1==ID, na.rm=TRUE)
    count[,1][i]<-unique_values1[i]
  }
  colnames(count)<-cbind("value","instances in dataset 1", "instances in dataset 2")
return(as.data.frame(count))
  }
```

Comment: If you are passing column name as a string into the function, then you need to subset the column based on the column name before converting to numeric

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest this `dplyr` approach and a built in function to avoid the loop. The function takes two arguments as strings which belong to the column names in each dataset. After that, it merges results:

```
library(dplyr)
#Function
myfun <- function(x,y)
{
  #Dataset 1
  r1 <- df1 %>% group_by(id=df1[,x]) %>% summarise(N1=n())
  #Dataset 2
  r2 <- df2 %>% group_by(id=df2[,y]) %>% summarise(N2=n())
  #Join
  r3 <- left_join(r1,r2)
  #Fill
  r3 %>% replace(is.na(.),0) -> r3
  return(r3)
}
#Apply function
myfun(x = 'UOF',y = 'Identifier')
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
     id    N1    N2
  <int> <int> <int>
1  1545     3     2
2  1588     2     0
3  1640     1     2
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df1 <- structure(list(UOF = c(1545L, 1588L, 1640L, 1545L, 1545L, 1588L
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
df2 <- structure(list(Identifier = c(1712L, 646L, 1545L, 1645L, 646L, 
1545L, 1640L, 1640L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

We could do this in a more simple way with `table` and `merge` without looping or using any external packages.  We just need the `unique` values of the first dataset to make the 'identifier' column a `factor` with `levels` assigned from the first dataset, get the `table` and do a `merge` (from `base R`)

```
join_analysis <- function(dat1, dat2, colnm1) {
        lvls <- unique(dat1[[colnm1]])
        tbl1 <- table(factor(dat1[[colnm1]], levels = lvls))
        tbl2 <- table(factor(dat2[[colnm1]], levels = lvls))
        out <- merge(tbl1, tbl2, by = 'row.names')[-c(1, 4)]
        names(out) <- c('value', 'instances in dataset 1',  
                  'instances in dataset 2')
        return(out)

}

join_analysis(UOF, Citations, 'identifier')
#   value instances in dataset 1 instances in dataset 2
#1  1545                      3                      2
#2  1588                      2                      0
#3  1640                      1                      2
```

---

Or another option is `pivot_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bind_rows(UOF, Citations, .id = 'grp') %>% 
   filter(identifier %in% unique(UOF$identifier)) %>%
   count(grp, identifier) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = grp, values_from = n, values_fill = 0)
```

---

Or another option is to do `count` in both datasets in a `list` and then `reduce` it with `left_join`

```
library(purrr)
list(UOF, Citations) %>%
   map(~ .x %>%
          count(identifier)) %>%
     reduce(left_join, by = 'identifier')
```

#### data

```
UOF <- structure(list(identifier = c(1545, 1588, 1640, 1545, 1545, 1588
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

Citations <- structure(list(identifier = c(1712, 646, 1545, 1645, 646, 1545, 
1640, 1640)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try `merge` + `stack` like below if you would like to be with base R

```
merge(aggregate(. ~ ind, stack(table(UOF)), sum),
  aggregate(. ~ ind, stack(table(Citations)), sum),
  by = "ind", all.x = TRUE
)
```

which gives

```
   ind values.x values.y
1 1545        3        2
2 1588        2       NA
3 1640        1        2
```

**Data**

```
UOF <- data.frame(identifier = c(1545, 1588, 1640, 1545, 1545, 1588))
Citations <- data.frame(identifier = c(1712, 646, 1545, 1645, 646, 1545, 1640, 1640))
```